# How to modify the content of an svg based dom using nodejs, d3 and jsdom?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, svg, jsdom

I am trying to assemble and host an svg using nodejs, jsdom and d3 v4.
I wrote an [updated version](https://gist.github.com/jpcofr/e9374bf437d15a76d7415c404f87575d) of [this example](https://gist.github.com/Caged/6407459) because it is not working as it is. However, I have to manually set the closing svg tag because I do not know how to add the path inside the body of the svg using d3.

How can I append the last path on the example inside the svg using d3?

**UPDATE 1**

This section from the [updated version](https://gist.github.com/jpcofr/e9374bf437d15a76d7415c404f87575d) manages to struct the main sections of the svg. After everything is appended, the second section tries to add the path data unsucessfully since the data is appended beyond the closing svg tag:

```
var document = jsdom.jsdom();
var svg = d3.select(document.body)

svg.append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .attr('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
    .attr('width', width + pad.l + pad.r)
    .attr('height', height + pad.t + pad.b)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + pad.l + ',' + pad.t + ')')
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .call(xAxis)
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('.axis text')
    .style('fill', '#888')
    .style('font-family', 'Helvetica Neue')
    .style('font-size', 11)
    .selectAll('.axis line')
    .style('stroke', '#eee')
    .style('stroke-width', 1)
    .selectAll('.domain')
    .style('display', 'none')

svg.selectAll('path.samples')
    .data([samples])
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'samples')
    .attr('d', line)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', '#c00')
    .style('stroke-width', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your selections

```
var document = jsdom.jsdom();
var body = d3.select(document.body)

var svg = body .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .attr('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
    .attr('width', width + pad.l + pad.r)
    .attr('height', height + pad.t + pad.b)

 // now we appending g element to the svg

   var g = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + pad.l + ',' + pad.t + ')')

   //now we are appending container for x axis inside g
        g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .call(xAxis)

    //now we are appending container for y axis inside g
        g
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis)


  // now we are styling appended axis texts inside svg
        svg.selectAll('.axis text')
        .style('fill', '#888')
        .style('font-family', 'Helvetica Neue')
        .style('font-size', 11)

  // now we are styling all ticks inside svg
        svg.selectAll('.axis line')
        .style('stroke', '#eee')
        .style('stroke-width', 1)

 // now we are styling both line inside svg again ()
        svg.selectAll('.domain')
        .style('display', 'none')


  // now we are appending paths to the svg




    svg.selectAll('path.samples')
        .data([samples])  //  if samples is array and you want to bind each element to the path, then [ ] this brackets is redundant here
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'samples')
        .attr('d', line)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', '#c00')
        .style('stroke-width', 2)
```

Comment: I got it almost working, but now the xml header is not being rendered by the server (i.e. only the g tags etc. come inside the response). I'm having trouble imagining how is the structure of the document affected while I append stuff... that is why I lose track of what is happening...